# Class of functions (similar to Lipschitz functions)

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. For a scalar $a\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists a positive scalar $C$ such that the following condition is satisfied:

$$\|f(x)-af(y)\|\leq C\|x-ay\|$$

Is this a restrictive condition? Does this condition have a name? I know it is called Lipschitz condition when $a=1$. What are the properties of such functions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Letting $x=ay$, we know that $f(ay)=af(y)$

Comment: Yes, but you restrict it to include only functions that satisfy the homogeneity property. This is a trivial case.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a\ne 0$, and let $x=ay$. The inequality gives us that $f(ay)=af(y)$, for each $y\in\mathbb R$.

Substituting this back into the inequality, we have that $\lVert f(x)-f(ay)\rVert\le C\lVert x-ay\rVert$, which is just the Lipschitz condition.

The converse is also true, i.e., your condition holds iff $f$ is Lipschitz and for each $y\in\mathbb R$, $f(ay)=af(y)$.